# Setting batch file value

Tags: batch-file

I want to add to an existing batch file.
I get an error in bamboo build output called make-ERROR, I want my bamboo build to fail whenever I see make-ERROR

My idea was to assign the value of 1 to make-ERROR, so the batch file would check if make-ERROR appears and if so stop the build, so in short if we get 1 stop everything if we get 0 continue.

Comment: Can you be more explicit; for example, what do you mean by "get an error called make-ERROR"? Is make-ERROR the name of the error? Is make-ERROR the actual output? What do you mean by "assign the value of 1 to make-ERROR"? Does that imply make-ERROR is actually a variable?

Comment: sure, the error is in the bamboo logs and is called make-ERROR. I don't want my builds to pass when this error appears, instead I want the builds to fail to prompt developers to see a build fail and investigate the error. My hope was to set a condition in the batch file to check for 1 or 0, 0 being we don't see the make-Error in the bamboo log and 1 being we do see make-Error in bamboo log.

Comment: `find "make-ERROR" "C:\path\to\bamboo-build-logs" >nul` and then check `%errorlevel%`.

Comment: thanks DodgyCodeException, I think this is what I was looking for